# set JavaME List index

Tags: list, java-me, indexing

im new with JavaME and need some help.

I wanna use a List-object and need to set the index of the entrys in this list..

I add entrys with the "list.addRecord(..)" function atm.
Works great, but how i said, i wanna set the entrys index'..

**Example**

with the "addRecord"function:

```
0 Entry1
1 Entry2
2 Entry3
...
```

what i need:

```
4 Entry1
1 Entry2
10 Entry3
...
```

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it.

1. Use [**Hashtable**](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Hashtable.html)

```
Hashtable list=new Hashtable();

list.put(new Integer(4),"Entry1");
list.put(new Integer(1),"Entry2");
list.put(new Integer(0),"Entry3");

x=list.get(new Integer(1)); // "Entry2"
```

2. Use two arrays (or Vectors)

```
int[]keys=new int[ITEM_COUNT]
String[]values=new int[ITEM_COUNT]

keys[0]=4; values[0]="Entry1";
keys[1]=1; values[1]="Entry2";
keys[2]=0; values[2]="Entry3";

int getValueByKey(int key) {
    for(int i=0;i<ITEM_COUNT;i++)
        if(keys[i]==key) return values[i];
    return -1; // No such key
}
x=getValueByIndex(1); // "Entry2"
```